# Can't get the correct number of buttons with specific class name

Tags: javascript, html

I want to count the number of buttons inside a div, I add the buttons dynamically from a js file. When I run the program on the browser, the buttons appear correctly and when I inspect the code from the browser all the elements and class names are correct. However, when I try to log the number of buttons with a class name of "accordion" it returns 0 when it should return 4.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<body class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="width: 100%;height: 50%;">
<div class="container" style="width: 500px;"><img src="assets/img/header_image.png" style="width: 100%;">        
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <div id="accordion-div" class="col">                                            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

The javascript code:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var acc_div = document.getElementById("accordion-div")
var i;

add_accordion_item = (name, details) => {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    acc_div.appendChild(btn);
    btn.innerHTML = name;
    btn.className += "btn btn-success accordion";
    btn.type = "button"

    var details = document.createElement('div');
    acc_div.appendChild(details);
    details.innerHTML = details
    details.className += "panel"
}
url = '.....'
make_list = () => {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){          
        for(var i = 0; i<data["number_of_threats"]; i++){        
            name = data["info"][i]["name"];          
            details = "details"
            add_accordion_item(name, details);
        }
    });
}

make_list()

console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("accordion").length)
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

This should show a button that when pressed it should show the div with the details. But the for never runs as the acc.length is 0.

Thanks for you time

Comment: Can you create a snippet or a fiddle for us to try this out?

Answer (score 0):

I think that a node array don't get length attribut.

You should use forEach instead of for loop like

```
acc.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function() {
       this.classList.toggle("active");
       var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
       if (panel.style.display === "block") {
           panel.style.display = "none";
       } else {
         panel.style.display = "block";
       }
    });
  })
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Maybe you can try another approach by creating a function to creating the listener and call it after the button creation

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed to add a class `accordion` as to any element. because I cant see any element with a class name as `accordion` in your html code.
But inside to your javascriptcode, on first line you are trying to search an element with a class name as `accordion`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `acc` doesn't auto update after you declared it in the beginning.

You will need to retrieve the value of `acc` variable again just above the for loop. 
i.e. just above the for loop you need to add the line like this

```
acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {

....
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the listener inside the make_list function

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var acc_div = document.getElementById("accordion-div")
var i;

add_accordion_item = (name, details) => {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    acc_div.appendChild(btn);
    btn.innerHTML = name;
    btn.className += "btn btn-success accordion";
    btn.type = "button"

    var details = document.createElement('div');
    acc_div.appendChild(details);
    details.innerHTML = details;
    details.className += "panel";
    add_listener(btn);
}
url = '.....'
make_list = () => {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){          
        for(var i = 0; i<data["number_of_threats"]; i++){        
            name = data["info"][i]["name"];          
            details = "details"
            add_accordion_item(name, details);
        }
    });
}

make_list()


function add_listener(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```